# Object not rotating right

Tags: mesh, rigging

https://gyazo.com/1bcb0ae93258d5d19efc42b5a008ec59

I tried parenting an object to a bone but when I rotate it it doesn't rotate as I expect, it is not supposed to leave a little gap between the horse body and the saddle, why does it rotate like that?

[image]

Comment: make sure, the deforming vertices of the saddle and the deforming vertices of the horseback have exactly the same weight to the bone. This looks like the weight of the horseback is higher right now, so it gets bent farther than the saddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the saddle to be "stuck" to the back of the character, you could parent it to 3 vertices of the face you want the saddle to be stuck to.

1. Select the saddle (<kbd>RMB</kbd>)
2. Add the horse to the selection (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>)
3. Toggle Edit Mode
4. Select 3 vertices
5. Make Vertex Parent (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)

Comment: Many thanks, it appears that it worked (I didn't know this little trick and I'm sure I'll use it again eventually)